# Homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose $\phi : S_4 \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2$ is a surjective homomorphism. Find $\ker\phi$. Determine all homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $\mathbb Z_2$.

My solution: since $\phi$ is surjective, then by the first isomorphism theorem, $S_4/\ker\phi \cong \mathbb Z_2$. Therefore, by computation, $\ker\phi = A_4$.

Now, for the second part, I have some trouble since they ask for all the possible homomorphisms. I know that the map that takes even permutations to $0$ and odd permutations to $1$ is a homomorphism. But, my question is: How to make sure this is the only one?

thanks,

Comment: You know the kernel, so you know what goes to zero, so, by default, you know what goes to 1.

Comment: Note that the second part asks for all homomorphisms, not just the surjective ones. So you need to find the non-surjective homomorphisms as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is another surjective homomorphism other than the sign homomorphism then we would (putting the two of them together) have a surjective homomorphism $S_4\rightarrow Z_2 \times Z_2$ or equivalently we would have a surjective homomorphism $A_4\rightarrow Z_2$. This leads to a subgroup of order 6 in $A_4$. But it is easy to see this is impossible. So the sign homomorphism is the unique non-trivial homomorphism $S_4\rightarrow Z_2$

Answer (score 2):

The kernel must contain $\frac{24}2=12$ elements and it must contain all even permutations. There's no room for choice.

Comment: Sir but I think different homomorphism can have same kernel? So how we can show there are only two homomorphisms from $S_4$ to $\mathbb{Z_2}$ please help.