# Find all homomorphism from $S_4$ to $z_m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find all homomorphism from $S_4$ to $z_m$.

The only normal subgroup of $S_4$ are trivial , entire group, $A_4$ and klein 4 group.

If m is odd , then there is only one homomorphism (trivial)... What if n is even?

My attempt.

If $6|n$ then there is 3 homomorphism of whose kernal is {e},$A_4$, klein 4 group.
 If $6 $ doesn't divide $n$ then there is only 2 homomorphism... Is this correct?

Comment: Does there exists a homorphism who kernal is klein 4 group?

Comment: Use `$\{ e\}$` for $\{ e\}$.

Comment: For $m=2$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219333/homomorphisms-from-s-4-to-mathbb-z-2?rq=1).

Comment: Do you know about the abelianization of a group, and in particular what the abelianization of $S_4$ is?

Comment: @Daniel nope...

Comment: OK, then, if I expand the argument I was thinking of, the key points are: 1. Any element of $S_4$ can be written as a product of transpositions. 2. Any two transpositions in $S_4$ are conjugate elements, which must therefore map to the same element $x \in \mathbb{Z} / \langle n \rangle$ since $\mathbb{Z} / \langle n \rangle$ is abelian. 3. Since the square of a transposition is the identity, the element $x$ must satisfy $x + x = 0$ (again, in the group $\mathbb{Z} / \langle n \rangle$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler so can I say that if $n$ is  even then always $2$ homomorphism ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sir can I say that if $n$ is even then always $2$ homomorphism .